# How do you mention a night between 2 days?

Tags: grammar

How do you mention a night between 2 days? Is it

1. "the night of the 23rd and the 24th"?
2. "the night from the 23rd to the 24th"?
3. "the night between the 23rd and  the 24th"?

Thanks.

Comment: "The night of the 23rd" is sufficient (even though, strictly speaking, it's the 24th once midnight is past).

Comment: If you really need to emphasize the entire period, you could say, "the night of the 23rd and the dawn of the 24th."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid misunderstandings (at a cost of creating a more wordy expression) the "The night of the 23rd/24th" or "23rd to 24th" are possible.  Generally this isn't needed, but there are times when there is no extra context, and avoidance of doubt makes this kind of expression permissible.

Answer (score 0):

"The night of the 23rd" is correct.

If you mention any other night, it will sound like you're talking about two nights, not just one.

Although technically nights both begin and end days, we only think of nights as ending days, so "the night of the 23rd" refers to the night at the end of the 23rd and beginning the 24th.